# How to read and modify meta data of a folder in High sierra (APFS)

Tags: objective-c, macos-high-sierra, apfs

I am not able to access .DS_store files in High Sierra. Do APFS store meta data of a folder somewhere else, How to read and modify meta data of a folder in APFS.

Answer (score 0):

You should never be reading and writing `.DS_store` files, they are private to the Finder. Depending on the metadata you are trying to read/write you might use `NSFileManager`, `NSURL`, the BSD/Posix functions covered in sections 2 & 3 of the Unix manual (the `man`) command, AppleScripting the Finder, etc. Time for some reading!

If you don't find your answer ask a new question, show what you've tried (or worked pre-APFS), what you've read, what exact metadata you're trying to read/write, etc. and someone will undoubtedly help you out.